# C# Column Break in Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, word-automation

I work in a three-column word document. I can insert a column break after a text, but I can't write it in the new column afterwards. What do I miss?

```
Word.Paragraph oPara4;
var oRng = document.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
oPara4 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(oRng);
oPara4.Range.InsertParagraphBefore();
oPara4.Range.Text = "Some Text Before the break";
oPara4.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;
oPara4.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

// Column Break
oPara4.Range.InsertBreak(Word.WdBreakType.wdColumnBreak);

// New Text in new column
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating Word document content it's a very good idea to work with dedicated `Range` objects to define the "targets".

The sample code below creates a `Range` object for `oPara4`. This makes it possible to "collapse" the `Range` to its end-point. (Think of it like pressing right-arrow when there's a selection to get a blinking cursort after what was selected.)

Collapsing the `Range` before inserting the column break ensures that everything created up to that point is not lost when writing new content (the column break) to the `Range`. After inserting the column break the `Range` is collapsed once more to its end-point, which is now in the next column.

```
        Word.Paragraph oPara4;
        var oRng = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(@"\EndOfDoc").Range;
        oPara4 = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(oRng);
        Word.Range rngPara = oPara4.Range;
        rngPara.InsertParagraphBefore();
        rngPara.Text = "Some Text Before the break";
        oPara4.Format.SpaceAfter = 24;
        rngPara.InsertParagraphAfter();
        rngPara.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);

        // Column Break
        rngPara.InsertBreak(Word.WdBreakType.wdColumnBreak);
        rngPara.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
        rngPara.Text = "next";
```